# How to get the key value from json using retrofit

Tags: kotlin, retrofit

I have a Json response like this ,How to get the date

```
     {
  "2019-04-08": [
{
  "path": "/HEdY2Ry1fIMVq0GmN5NipS62SMcHpGH6ocZ0PU0p.png",
  "org_name": "bmi_icon.png"
},
{
  "path": "/v5QvdZfpZgGHh3ZfWNlvpTKYssXItbl1M6aaxlCJ.png",
  "org_name": "heartrate.png"
}
  ],
   "2019-04-01": [
{
  "path": "/L6xuyZGhy0giq8K4rxGnkcO1OND9lRzDrDHvokol.png",
  "org_name": "avatar.png"
}
  ],
  "2019-04-04": [
{
  "path": "/lRwBmuVMPv1AWdo00onOy5eOXuCacvfbfBVAaCZ1.jpeg",
  "org_name": "bp.jpg"
}
  ],
    "2019-04-10": [
{
  "path": "/aA5rV0FAStrtCH328jX9lLwHYRCIo8TuQ7f0PouV.png",
  "org_name": "Screenshot_20180717-183728.png"
}
  ]
}
```

I need to get the date from the response

I need to get the date  for every loop

Answer (score 0):

So I believe retrofit allows for manual usage of gson, as per [leveraging gson](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Leveraging-the-Gson-Library)

The structure of the json you have described means that you do not have a kotlin land object at the top level, but a kotlin land Map. If you have any control over the API you are consuming, try not to put Maps at the top level - what is it a map of? Ideally you have a nice well defined object at the top level, and it has fields in it which convey the semantics of the data they encasulate. But, that is an asside.

Let us define an object that your dates map to:

```
data class ImageMapping(
        val path: String,
        val org_name: String
)
```

And then, for your particular data structure, you will need to use a direct call of your Retrofit service and access the body of the response directly. Once you have that, you can deserialize it yourself. I do not know how or what your endpoints look like, and this question is not about wiring up Retrofit I think, it is about deserializing json with a Map as the top object. Hopefully this is enough for you to wire it into your own code:

```
    val call = yourRetrofitService.getYourData(yourArgument)
    val result = call.execute().body()
    val gson = Gson()
    val type = object : TypeToken<Map<String, List<ImageMapping>>>() {}.type
    val map: Map<String, List<ImageMapping>> = gson.fromJson(result, type)
    map.forEach{entry ->
        println(entry.key) // This should be your dates.
    }
```

The key part to get json to work with the Map type in Kotlin is to define that TypeToken.

Comment: where should i add this code and how will my model class look..??@Laurence

Comment: @RT16 - I updated the answer, hopefully that is enough for you to adjust your own code to do a manual deserialization of that Map.